# How to center bootstrap navbar, but also pull 1 element right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was able to center my navbar with the CSS below.  Now I want to put another element but pull that to the right. However, when I add the icon, it drops down to the next line. How do I center my navbar and add the icon, while keeping everything inline?

This is a piece of my navbar with the css.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="text-align: center;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:18px; display: inline-block;"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  @media (min-width: 708px){
  .navbar-nav{
     float:none;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
    }
  }
```

Comment: what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the "top" property on the element then give it a negative value to correctly position your search icon.

```
.search {
  top: -50px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

If necessary, adding additional navigation links wont't break style .
[See my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xlez1htMgmycr2MTfYVR?p=preview)

Also, you may take out the styles in your HTML tags.